# Google search console doesn't allow me to move to a new domain that has a path

Tags: seo, google-search-console, domains, 301-redirect

Gwt notify me that I can moved my old domain (`www.olddomain.com`) to my new domain only if there's no path on my new domain. But in this case, I have to move my old domain (`www.olddomain.com`) to (`www.newdomain.co/id`) with `/id`.

The new domain with a path is a must, I can't change it. What should I do? I don't want to lose my SEO juice.

Comment: `/id` is a subdirectory or path, not a subdomain, I edited your question to correct that.  Do your redirects point to the correct new path?   If so, you can probably just move it from domain to domain without specifying the new path.

Comment: yeah, thank you. i'm new in this field.

my new domain (www.newdomain.co) is already have pages. thats why we redirect my old domain (www.olddomain.com) to (www.newdomain.co/id).
is it fine? or idk. i never done 301 redirect before.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are talking about the change of address tool. It does have some limitations, but its submission is also a very insignificant part of a migration process.

The most important thing is that you have set up page to page 301 redirects from your old pages to the new ones.

I'd also make sure I've verifies every site involved with the Google Search Console and submitted your sitemap in them.

p.s. /id is not a subdirectory. Subdirectories should end in a slash. e.g. /id/ Which I presume is your case. Your system may be set up so that /id still works.